# Spark Streaming - How to get the "Key" in updateStateByKey function

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

I'm using the updateStateByKey function in Spark Streaming application to persist and update the status for each key. The question is I want to know the **"key"** inside the update function.

```
input.updateStateByKey(updateStateByKeyOfUsers)

def updateStateByKeyOfUsers(newUsers: Seq[Set[String]],
                          userStatus: Option[(#####)]
                           ): Option[(#####)] = {
   //How to get the "Key"
}
```

-Tao

Comment: Do not you think it would be helpful if you were shared the type of `input`? Based on [this example](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/examples/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/examples/streaming/StatefulNetworkWordCount.scala#L74) I think the key is `t._1` in line 55, though your method signature looks very different. Does it compile?

Answer (score 4):

Generally speaking, Spark API does not let you obtain a key. Which is quite sad. You have two options: either include a key in each of inputs or include it in a state.